# How can i check the panel status

Tags: c#, asp.net, panel

How can I check the current status of an asp panel? I want to check the current status of the panel as to whether it is enabled or disabled. If it is enabled, then i'll do something in the code behind. Please help me to check it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From code behind side you can check it as

```
if(PanelName.Enabled)
```

If it returns true that means it will post back.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for [`WebControl.Enabled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/afw857ha%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) property:

```
var isEnabled = panel.Enabled;
```

> When the `Enabled` property of a control is set to false, the control
>   typically appears dimmed. If the control is an input element, the
>   browser prevents the user from clicking or typing in it. HTML elements
>   that are rendered for a server control are marked as disabled by
>   setting their disabled attribute or their CSS class attribute.